# .htaccess PHP Rewrite Rules

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file and it worked perfectly

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$ index.php?ID=$1
```

http://example.com/ipad.html

but i have a problem when the the url ( id) Contains slashes

for example

id=1/4ABCD Which gives this url (http://example.com/1/4ABCD.html)

Please how resolve this problem?

Comment: Dont use slashes in URL's. They're always part of the syntax

Comment: But the id Contains slashes

Comment: It shouldn't. A slash is used for determining folder levels. You'll have to change your data.